# Running Selenium on Azure Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App that I want to use to screen scrape a website when I call an Action on a controller, like so.

```
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.Url = "http://url.com";
driver.Navigate();
var source = driver.PageSource;
var pathElement = driver.FindElementByXPath("//table[@class='someclassname']");

string innerHtml = "";
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
if (js != null)
{
    innerHtml = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", pathElement);
}
return innerHtml;
```

This works fine locally, however when I upload to my Azure Web App, I get this error

> Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:51169/

I assume this has to do with firewalls since I need to approve PhantomJS in my firewall settings the first time the app runs. My question is how do I get this to work deployed in Azure? Is it even possible, or do I need to configure this as some Unit Test and run it from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? Because I'm in the same boat.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working?  How about you @Martin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PhantomJS does not work today in the sandbox that Azure Web Apps run under. See the [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks) for a list of things that are known to not work currently, as well as lots of other information about the sandbox.

Comment: I see, do you know of something like ChomeDriver work in Azure?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know, but it may be worth trying. Unfortunately, the GDI restrictions do block a lot of scenarios in this space.

Comment: @IsaacLevin have you tried run ChromeDriver in Azure?

Comment: @kotoj I ended us using AngleSharp, worked perfectly

Comment: @IsaacLevin I need rendered web page, especially need to make screenshots. So it seems that AngleSharp does not solve my problem, am I right? Thank you for quick answer anyway! :)

Comment: My situation I needed post JavaScript executed Dom so it worked for me. If you need to screen cap, I doubt it will give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would rethink your solution of using Selenium here. Selenium is used to automate manual testing of your webapp. Basically, automate filling out a form, click a button, etc.

Even if Selenium and your PhantomJS Driver does run on your Azure webapp without issues, you'll have a bottleneck of one browser per 1 Http request. I suspect you'll run into performance problems real soon.

Furthermore, the time it takes for drivers to load PhantomJS, request a page, interact, and close PhantomJS is slow.

In your case, it sounds like you're not interacting with your source site, you just need data. So perhaps just parsing the HTML DOM will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I will post here this snippet that works on Azure. It is however far from usable in production as I keep getting random connection errors such as:

> Unable to connect to the remote server inner message: Unable to connect to the remote server inner message: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

The exact same code works well on a console or windows application environment.

```
PhantomJSDriver driver = null;
        PhantomJSDriverService service;

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
            (
               delegate { return true; }
            );

        int retry = 0;

        while (driver == null && retry < 3)
        {
            try
            {
                service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                var uri = service.ServiceUrl;
                var port = service.Port;
                service.LocalToRemoteUrlAccess = true;
                var ghostDriverPath = service.GhostDriverPath;
                service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                service.Start();

                var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
                driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service, options);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (driver != null)
                {
                    driver.Close();
                    driver.Quit();
                    driver = null;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(retry * 1500);

                ServiceAudit.Default.TraceDebug($"Starting web driver failed on {retry} try");
            }
            retry++;
        }

        if (driver == null)
        {
            ServiceAudit.Default.TraceError($"Web driver could not be started");
        }

        return driver;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you should be doing is publishing to an Azure WebRole. 
Check out this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532701/1486716