# PhantomJs webdriver issue on Azure web job Exception- Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:51293/

Tags: azure, selenium, phantomjs, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I am working with Phantomjs web diver to get page source .it's working fine on local but when i host webjob on azure then its giving me exception;

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:51293/

http://localhost:51293/ this path changed at every run .

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900225/phantomjs-as-web-job-in-azure

Comment: Yes David, i have tried all but its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJS is not supported by Azure Web App/Web Jobs currently. It is noted in the end of following official document.

[Azure Web App sandbox - Unsupported frameworks](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks)

*Other scenarios that are not supported: PhantomJS/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses GDI+.*

Comment: Ok Thanks - amor

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If my reply is helpful for you, please mark it as answer. A thread which has an answer will be easily searched. It will help other community members who encountered a similar problem.

Comment: Just publish to a Web/Worker Role instead (Cloud Services), it works beautifully, i'm running PhantomJS with the headless Phantom driver in a small Web Role instance for quite some time, zero issues.

Comment: @evilSnobu please share your code, I've been trying to make this solution work but haven't managed to arrive at a stable, production quality solution

Comment: Here's the MVC Controller -
 https://gist.github.com/snobu/131c210e3b3d79e305de4f5b16f8bef9. Really nothing special, just a Cloud Service with a WebRole.