# Host Selenium C# project on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, selenium

I have a selenium C# project build using Chrome driver that scrapes 5 different websites for prices and adds the data into SQL. They project works pretty fine on local machine. I want to deploy it on Azure server.

1. Which Azure service to be used for this?
2. Is there any code sample availabe?

Answer (score 0):

> Host Selenium C# project on Azure

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683608/running-selenium-on-azure-web-app) discussed "Running Selenium on Azure Web App", and we can find Selenium project seems can not run in the [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) that Azure Web Apps run under.

[Azure Virtual Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/) is another hosting option, if possible, you can create a Azure Virtual Machine and migrate your project to that VM.

Comment: What about the http trigger? How shall we configure the httpTrigger on the virtual machine and how we will expose it to end users?